# What was the **exact** reason to turn the Demon Slayer: train arc into episodes?

Tags: anime-production, demon-slayer

[This previous question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/65825/is-the-adaptation-of-the-kimetsu-no-yaiba-movie-mugen-ressha-hen-the-second-sea) got me into thinking:

> What was the *reason* to turn the turn the Demon Slayer: train arc into episodes?

The train arc of *Demon Slaye*r was adapted into movie which performed very well globally. It smashed many records and became the Japan's highest grossing film of all time surpassing *Spirited Away*. Since the movie performed very well, why did they had to turn the movie into episodes for season 2? Maybe the episodes will feature new scenes that didn't made into the movie and will elaborate on particular scenes. But it was not necessary to show the same thing again.

Both the movie and the TV series are adapted by the same studio (Ufotable) and produced by the same producers (Aniplex, Shueisha). So, there was no discrepancy in the studio and broadcasters POV. So, was it for financial gain? Or is there any other reason? Why didn't they pick after the train arc and jump into the district arc which I believe will be 13 episodes and thus form 1 cour instead of stopping at an awkward episode count?

Comment: Unrelated, but it reminded me of [*Boruto* the movie and *Boruto* the anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/48051/2516)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't really read into the creator's minds, but in the absence of official or insider statements, it is difficult to consider a reason other than "money".

As the [source](https://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/articles/2109/27/news132.html) given an answer in the [previous question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/65825/is-the-adaptation-of-the-kimetsu-no-yaiba-movie-mugen-ressha-hen-the-second-sea) linked in the question states, the anime will take the movie and add a few new scenes to it. This means fans who watched the movie will likely watch the anime (including the duplicate parts) as well to see all the extra scenes, and reusing the movie means they can fill out runtime without having to animate the parts from the movie again. Essentially this lets them double-dip - get the cinematic revenue from the theatrical release, as well as the streaming/TV revenue from the "free" extra runtime of the anime.

Of course, it also means that the fans who didn't watch the movie in theaters and can't be bothered to purchase it anywhere else, as well as those who may not even know that the movie exists (particularly future fans who enter the series long after its completion) do not miss anything by just watching the anime. (although personally I'd be surprised if there are ever any significant number of people who like *Demon Slayer* who did not watch the best grossing anime movie of all time)

Here is [a link to an article](https://comicbook.com/anime/news/demon-slayer-season-2-mugen-arc-repeat/) that basically says the same thing as this answer.